# Exporting prometheus metrics of sync vs async python apps

Tags: python, monitoring, prometheus

I have a minimal async python server based on `aiohttp`.

It is very straightforward, just a websocket endpoint exposed as in

```py
@routes.get('/my_endpoint')
async def my_func(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    return ws
```

I want to expose as `prometheus` metrics the request rate (and potentially the error rate).

After performing a brief investigation on the topic, I realised that it seems like there is a distinction between approaching prometheus metrics exposure when it comes to [sync](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/monitoring-your-synchronous-python-web-applications-using-prometheus/) vs [async](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/monitoring-your-asynchronous-python-web-applications-using-prometheus/) apps.

For my case, where I want a simple request count/rate, is there a reason not to just use the plain' old prometheus python client (e.g by simply [decorating](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#three-step-demo) `my_func`?)

Would the request count actually fail in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on my understanding on `asyncio` and the way the [official prometheus client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) describes how it exposes metrics.
`aiohttp` is to be used on top of `asyncio`. Now, `asyncio` is running something called an "event loop" which runs inside a single thread ([usually the main thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading))

You can look at it as an entity that decides to suspend or execute functions that were assigned to run in the loop. In your case `my_func`.
For `prometheus_client` to expose your metrics you will probably need to run it in a *different thread*

> Metrics are usually exposed over HTTP, to be read by the Prometheus server. The easiest way to do this is via start_http_server, which will start a HTTP server in a daemon thread on the given port

This is outside "the control of the event loop" which might lead to performance issues and to unexpected behavior as a result. So the request count might not fail, but if for some reason its doing some blocking task (I/O) it will block the main thread as well. If you'd use the async approach and run it as part of the event loop your blocking task can be awaited and give back the control to the main thread.
There are open source projects that support prometheus in async functions such as [aioprometheus](https://aioprometheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/index.html) and [prometheus-async](https://prometheus-async.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).